# Macbook freezes while charging

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, freeze, battery

This MacBook(version 2.1) freezes while in OSX(10.5 and 10.6 at least) when in the charger is plugged after having ram upgraded to 4gbs. It doesn't freeze immediately but it always does eventually. The mouse is still moveable.

Works fine when booted into windows and in osx when not charging. Tried a clean install, no help.

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: If the mouse can still be moved when it's frozen, what do you mean by frozen?

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same problem. Was it the RAM? Because I tried using my colleague's RAM and the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting the old ram back in and seeing if it freezes? It could always be bad ram. Are you sure it is the right ram for your computer? Macs can be very picky about ram in my experience.